# IOS 5 Using App Delegate To Load a Modal

Tags: iphone, ios5

i'm building an app for ios5 and i have the following problem:

In ios4 when i need to present a login modal view on app start i do the following: 
in the AppDelegate i load it in method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions using the referenced  View Controller.

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate,LoginViewControllerDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    UITabBarController *tabBarController; //THIS

    UIView *splashView;

    User *user;
}
```

But now, in ios5 using storyboards, i can't find how to do this because in my AppDelegate i don't have any reference to any view controller and i don't know how to get them.

Any idea about this?

Thanks

Comment: iOS5 still under NDA. Try posting in Apple Developer Forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But why don't you just add a new Tabviewcontroller in MainStoryboard?
Using storyboards is much easier than writing a code in AppDelegate.